# To use MSMQ or WCF - VS 2008

Tags: c#

This is my situation:
1. have an existing application which relies on XML being fed via FTP. Based on the XML, the application performs tasks.

2. Now i want to download files, path being an element of the XML file, using BITS
3. I want to create a BITS application and that should work on the download aspect of the project when application in step 1 fires a message to the BITS application.

Application in step 1 is in VS-2003 and one version is in VS-2005. I want to create my BITS application in VS-2008, and if I cant use BITS then I would use curlHTTP to do a HTTP GET. The ? is do I use MSQM or WCF to send a message between application in step 1 and my download application?

Answer (score 1):

WCF has native support for MSMQ queues.

There are two types of bindings which may apply in your case...

NetMSMQBinding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netmsmqbinding.aspx

MSMQIntegrationBinding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.msmqintegration.msmqintegrationbinding.aspx

With these bindings you should be able to communicate directly to MSMQ queues.

Therefore, I do not think it's a case of either-or for WCF.  Either you need MSMQ or you do not.

(WCF is very powerful, but very hard to master.  I am in the process of writing my own framework for self-hosting WCF Services in Windows Services at the moment.)

Comment: EnocNRoll: without using MSQM, my other option would be NamedPipes. Webservice seems to be out of question due to restrictions. NamedPipes - they always been painful so am trying to avoid named pipes.

Comment: WCF has a NetNamedPipeBinding for using NamedPipes as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx